# is there an API for Google's Scribe auto-completing service?

Tags: autocomplete

Is there a way to use Google's Scribe autocomplete service (in Google Labs) through an api - you give it a word or words and it completes it?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is still no official API for Google Scribe. But to play around a bit, you could use the same API calls like Google Scribe is using. Just check the AJAX calls they are making while you're typing.

Here is an example call with curl:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"method":"scribe.textSuggestions.get","id":"scribe.textSuggestions.get","params":{"query":". this is a t","cp":40},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"scribe.textSuggestions.get","apiVersion":"v1"}' https://www.googleapis.com/rpc?key=AIzaSyBStAcD4WoVx3l1Cmc8xKvJTm2c0G2eqH4
```